# loop or apply for sum of R dataframe values based on multiple conditions meeting outside variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a starting data frame that looks something like what is below. Same basic format (titles, all relevant values are numeric. Same trait that Time.Start and Time.End have smaller amounts of unique values

```
 #df1
     Time.Start  Time.End   Lead   Result   Count
  [1]         1         0      1        1       1
  [2]         2         1      1       .5       1
  [3]         1         0      1        1       1
  [4]         3         1      1        0       1
  [5]         6         2      2        1       1
  [6]         4         3      2        0       1
  [7]         5         2      1        1       1
  [8]         3         1      1        0       1
  [9]         3         2      2        1       1
 [10]         2         0      2        1       1
 [11]         7         2      1        0       1
 [12]         2         1      1       .5       1
 [13]         9         0      2        1       1
 [14]         0         0      2        1       1         
 [15]         8         3      1       .5       1
```

I want to take those values and put them into a dataframe or matrix that looks like this.

```
Time <- 0:10
#df2
Time                                                                  Lead.1 
   0   sum(Result)/sum(Count) at df$Lead=1 df$Time.Start>=0 & df$Time.End<=0         
   1   sum(Result)/sum(Count) at df$Lead=1 df$Time.Start>=1 & df$Time.End<=1
   2   sum(Result)/sum(Count) at df$Lead=1 df$Time.Start>=2 & df$Time.End<=2
 ...                                                                     ...
  10 sum(Result)/sum(Count) at df$Lead=1 df$Time.Start>=10 & df$Time.End<=10
```

The trick here is that I can't just find every point where Time equals either Time.Start or Time.End, I also need every point where Time falls between or matches a row's Time.Start or Time.End. So for Time=2, from the example df I'd want the sum of values in rows, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12. A different vector would be created for each different lead value, with all leads of 4 or more being condensed into a single

If I wanted to generate this manually, I could. The formula below could be used to find it any time and for any lead.

```
sum(df[df$Lead==1 & df$Time.End<=t & df$Time.Start>=t,"Result")]/ 
sum(df[df$Lead==1 & df$Time.End<=t & df$Time.Start>=t,"Count")]
```

That isn't a practical solution as the actual data set has 300 different values of time, not 11. I first tried to create a for loop

```
    Lead1 <- for(i in Time){ 
          sum(df$Lead.Group=="1" & df[df$Time.End<=i & df$Time.Start>=i,"Result"])/
          sum(df$Lead.Group=="1" & df[df$Time.End<=i & df$Time.Start>=i,"Count"])
   }
```

That only output a couple hundred "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" error messages. I got the same results when using a by() function.

If relevant, the goal after generating the second dataframe is to create a scatterplot off each leads value changing over time. That should be pretty easily manageable with ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

Consider again running `by` to slice data frame by *Lead* groups and build a list of vectors that calculates your sum ratios across the *Time* sequence. From the resulting list of objects, run `do.call(cbind, ...)` to combine all vectors for final matrix output:

**Data**

```
txt <- 'Time.Start  Time.End   Lead   Result   Count
  1         0      1        1       1
  2         1      1       .5       1
  1         0      1        1       1
  3         1      1        0       1
  6         2      2        1       1
  4         3      2        0       1
  5         2      1        1       1
  3         1      1        0       1
  3         2      2        1       1
  2         0      2        1       1
  7         2      1        0       1
  2         1      1       .5       1
  9         0      2        1       1
  0         0      2        1       1         
  8         3      1       .5       1'

df1 <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)
df1
```

**Code**

```
Time <- 0:10

mat_list <- by(df1, df1$Lead, function(sub){
  # CURRENT LEAD NAME
  leadcol <- paste0("Lead.", sub$Lead[[1]])  

  # BUILD NAMED NUMERIC VECTOR ACROSS TIME
  vec_list <- lapply(Time, function(t) {
    mask <- sub$Time.Start >= t & sub$Time.End <= t
    setNames(sum(sub[mask,"Result"])/sum(sub[mask, "Count"]), leadcol)
  })
  do.call(rbind, vec_list)
})

# BUILD MASTER MATRIX
final_mat <- cbind(Time, do.call(cbind, mat_list))
final_mat

#       Time    Lead.1    Lead.2
#  [1,]    0 1.0000000 1.0000000
#  [2,]    1 0.5000000 1.0000000
#  [3,]    2 0.3333333 1.0000000
#  [4,]    3 0.3000000 0.7500000
#  [5,]    4 0.5000000 0.6666667
#  [6,]    5 0.5000000 1.0000000
#  [7,]    6 0.2500000 1.0000000
#  [8,]    7 0.2500000 1.0000000
#  [9,]    8 0.5000000 1.0000000
# [10,]    9       NaN 1.0000000
# [11,]   10       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: That works. I'm unfamiliar with the cbind, rbind, and do.call functions, so some clarification as to what exactly they are doing in the code would be appreciated. 

Also, may I ask how the code would change if instead of using integer column Lead, you used a factor column Lead.Group?  

`E.G`
`Time.Start    <- 1 5 4 3 2   1 0`
`Time.End     <- 0 3 2 1 1   0 0`
`Lead.Group <- 1 2 2 3 4+ 2 1`
`Result          <- 1 1 2 1 3   0 2`